# What are com.sec.android.provider.* apps exactly?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, provider

I know it's not a code question. However, i try to work on some databases that stored in directories like `/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.*`.

What does it mean by "sec" in the provider signature? Does it depend on the manufacture provider?

One example: the content provider for `call_logs` reads the database in `/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider` on a Samsung. What read the same content provider on an HTC?

Im a bit confused...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> However, i try to work on some databases that stored in directories like /data/data/com.sec.android.provider.*.

Those are not part of the Android SDK.

> What does it mean by "sec" in the provider signature?

Samsung Electronics Corporation is my guess.

Comment: i was under the impression at first it meant SECurity.. but your explanation makes much more sense .. it helped me today when trying to salvage a sdcard crash on my phone (trying to retrace what is installed and removing corrupted/incomplete apps)