# What can com.sec.android.app.launcher be used for?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-launcher

Can `com.sec.android.app.launcher` be used to hide or disguise messages, texts, or apps on your phone? I am encountering an issue that I can't post about on here, but knowing what this apk can do would help greatly.

Comment: look over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988424/what-are-com-sec-android-provider-apps-exactly

Answer (score 3):

you should be using samsung phone with samsung touchwiz UI on top of android. This should be launcher app customized by samsung.

com.sec.android.* is used normally used by samsung

Answer (score 1):

Here I was looking for ‍‍‍cdfs mode launcher when I come across this old post. Hmm... Now I'll throw my 2 cents in:

The `{.sec.}` in a `manifest.xml` files that I have come across changes the name compared to the other ones w/o it. Looks something like this:

```
<name>android.hardware.audio.effect</name>
And: <name>IEffectsFactory</name>
```

Open that and it's readable:

```
Compared to: <name>vendor.samsung.hardware.gnss</name>
And: <name>ISecGnss</name>
```

Open this and it will freak you out! All kinds of wing dings looking symbols instead of text.

Comment: @AdamLink Ok, thanks for the info!
I had just found a couple launchers & was trying them out I poking around under the

Answer (score 0):

Per [this extensive list of apps that are safe or dangerous to remove from your phone](http://www.downloads.galaxyunlocker.com/List-of-bloatware-apps-safe-to-remove-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-S2-GalaxyUnlocker.com.pdf), the particular package `com.sec.android.app.launcher` is **TouchWiz Home** which is a [Launcher](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/android_launcher.html) provided by default on your phone.

You should only remove this if you have another launcher installed.